# datatable in vb.net keep rightmost column with data in and remove empty columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, uipath

I have a DataTable with the below data which I'm wanting to format and just have the most recent weeks data.

| ID | Name | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Conor | 100 | 87 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Frank | 35 | 70 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Jeff | 35 | 13 | 0 | 57 |

I would like to keep the first 2 columns and then keep the right most column that isn't 0 giving me the following

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Conor | 3 |
| 2 | Frank | 70 |
| 3 | Jeff | 57 |

I'm quite new to LINQ so I'm a little unsure if it's possible to do this or not so any help would be appreciated.

Additional Info: I forgot to mention that I'm creating the solution in UiPath (an RPA tool) so although VB Code would be better for this instance LINQ is preferable.

Comment: How is the `DataTable` being loaded with data?

Comment: I'm populating it from an Excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is cool but working code is even cooler. Linq isn't necessarily faster. It does the loops internally.

Your code in the `GetDataTable` function would be the extraction of the data from Excel. I just built a DataTable to match your example.

In the button click event I created a table to hold the result. The outer loop goes through each row in the source `DataTable`. The inner `For` loop starts at the right most column in the `dtSource`  and steps back to the third column (index 2). Note the `Step -1`. This should work for any number of Week columns since we use `dtSource.Columns.Count - 1` As soon as it finds an non zero value it adds a record to `dtResult` and exits the inner `For` going on to the next row in `dtSource`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dtSource = GetDataTable()
    Dim dtResult As New DataTable
    dtResult.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
    dtResult.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    dtResult.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Integer))
    For Each row As DataRow In dtSource.Rows
        For i = dtSource.Columns.Count - 1 To 2 Step -1
            If CInt(row(i)) <> 0 Then
                dtResult.Rows.Add({row("ID"), row("Name"), row(i)})
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtResult
End Sub

Private Function GetDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Week1", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Week2", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Week3", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Week4", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Rows.Add({1, "Conor", 100, 87, 3, 0})
    dt.Rows.Add({2, "Frank", 35, 70, 0, 0})
    dt.Rows.Add({3, "Jeff", 35, 13, 0, 57})
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Completely agree and in a perfect world this is the type of solution I would probably implement. The problem I'm facing is that I'm implementing the solution in UiPath and although we can `Invoke Code` similar to above it would be preferable of it could be achieved using LINQ statements